# How much safe it is to use Serverless approach for BFSI

Tags: devops, serverless, aws-serverless, serverless-architecture

I am new to serverless architecture. I am about to create a banking application. Is it a good idea to develop my whole system using 100% serverless architecture (using AWS Lambda) or should it be a hybrid combination of both Serverless and Kubernetes Clustering. Thanks in advance

Comment: Concepts such as "safe" and "good idea" are totally up to you. Nobody external to your organization will be able to tell you what is best for your particular system. It all depends on your architecture and how the system is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

So long as you set your IAM access policies accordingly, secure your API Gateway endpoints with rotating keys on KMS, while using Cognito to provide JWT authentication for your users, then the short answer is yes (IMO). I have implemented quick and secure solutions with the new AWS secrets solution to store and rotate application secrets quickly and easily, if you're working on a banking app they also have a great HSM service that I think you will find valuable. I personally have no problem with AWS "lock-in", I value my time and peace of mind. You might want to check this out https://aws.amazon.com/security/